# python 3.7 urllib.request.urlretrieve HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python, requests, urllib

Всем салют!
Необходимо скачать изображение с сайта, но для того что бы скачать, нужно авторизоваться.
Авторизация проходит успешно, но при скачке все равно ответ HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager(ca_certs=certifi.where())

payload = {'UserName': 'Login', 'UserPassword': 'Password'}
encoded_data = json.dumps(payload).encode('utf-8')

resp = http.request(
     'POST',
     'https://mysite.ru/Login',
     body=encoded_data,
     headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

data = json.loads(resp.data.decode('utf-8'))
urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://mysite.ru/img/1", f"tmp/test.jpg")
```

Пробовал также использовать requests, но от него сервер не принимал авторизацию.

---

Воспользовался ещё раз requests

```
s = requests.session()
headers = {
    
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36',
    'ForceUseSession': 'true'
}
data={'UserName': 'UserName': 'Login', 'UserPassword': 'Password'}
p = s.post('https://mysite.ru/Login', headers=headers, data=data)
s.cookies
```

Получил ответ:

```
        requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - "POST /Login HTTP/1.1" 400 3069
ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Request Error</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <p class="heading1">Request Error</p>
      <p>The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'There was an error checking start element of object of type Core.ServiceModelContract.AuthToken. Encountered unexpected character 'U'.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is: </p>
      <p>   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.IsStartObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterMessageFormatter.ReadObject(Message message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterDataContractMessageFormatter.ReadObject(Message message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Не может сервер не принимать авторизацию от requests, значит вы неправильно передавали данные через него.

Comment: А по поводу вашего вопроса, сам с синтаксисом urllib не знаком, но скорее всего вам нужно создать аналог сессии, из под которой произвести и авторизацию и запрос картинки. Плюс не помешало бы указать хедеры, возможно сайт блокирует вас по тому же юзер-агенту. В requests сессия выглядит примерно так: with requests.Session() as req: Поищите такое же для urllib.

Comment: @Egettl вот код с использованием requests
`headers = {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36'
        }
        p = requests.post('https://mysite.ru/Login', data={'UserName': 'Login', 'UserPassword': 'Password'}) `

Но в ответ получаю

`requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - "POST /Login HTTP/1.1" 403 77
<h1>Forbidden</h1><pre>Request ID: 2020-12-03-00-06-23-5</pre>`

Comment: добавил в шапку код с requests.session

Comment: Нашел решение:
 p = s.post('https://mysite.ru/Login', headers=headers, data=data)
заменить на
 p = s.post('https://mysite.ru/Login', headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))